# Store System.Uri in Sqlite3

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, sqlite-net

I decided to use SQLite3 in my .NET application and I have some `System.Uri` properties defined in my entities.
I'm trying to use [SQLite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net), doing:

```
var myEntities = 
    Enumerable
    .Range(1, 100)
    .Select(id =>
        new MyEntity()
        {
            Id = id,
            StringProp = $"{nameof(MyEntity)} #{id}",
            DateTimeProp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(id),
            UriProp = new Uri("...")
        });

using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(dbFilePath))
{
    conn.CreateTable<MyEntity>();
    conn.InsertAll(myEntities);
}
```

but all I get is a: `"System.NotSupportedException: 'Don't know about System.Uri'"`.

Is there a way to keep using a `System.Uri` and save it as `string`?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you need from the URI, let's say you want the absolute uri:

```
string uristring = uri_variable.AbsoluteUri;
```

You can also retrieve the original string used to construct the uri:

```
string uristring = uri_variable.OriginalString;
```

This way you still use the URI but you save it in SQLite as a string.

EDIT:

The library throws an exception (line 2080 of Sqlite.cs) because the type System.Uri is not taken in consideration. 
I think it can be added in the list and then translated to varchar(100) as an example. Of course this is not tested, and I believe saving it as string should be the way to go.

Comment: The problem here is that SQLite data types do not include `Uri`s natively, so I'm wondering if there's some sort of mapping functionality (like an attribute or mapping method) to let SQLite/-net know how to serialize (and deserialize) a `System.Uri` object, and which type affinity to use.

Comment: Does it crash in conn.CreateTable ?

Comment: Yes: as I wrote, it raises a `System.NotSupportedException` saying "Don't know about System.Uri"

Comment: at the 2080, you can see where it throws the exception. You can play and put another case like:  else if (clrType == typeof(System.Uri)) {
return "varchar(100)"; (example)

Comment: Wow, whoever wrote SQLite-net obviously does not know how types work in SQLite...